# How to access data present in one controller by two pages in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, angular-material

I have data `vm.rslt` in `toolbar.controller.js` like and now I want to access that from 2 pages like `toolbar.html` and `sharedwishlistdetails.html`. But now I am getting result only in `toolbar.html` page. I have created a path for second page in `toolbar.module.js` and injected, but still I am not getting. Please help me to fix this.
That toolbar folder contains structure like below,

```
`sharedwishlistdetails.html
 sharedwishlistdetails.scss
 toolbbar.controller.js
 toolbar.html
 toolbar.module.js
 tolbar.scss`
```

### toolbbar.controller.js

```
(function ()
{
  'use strict';

   angular
    .module('app.toolbar')
    .controller('ToolbarController', ToolbarController);


    function ToolbarController($rootScope, $mdSidenav, msNavFoldService, $translate, $mdToast, $location, $localStorage, $http,  $scope)
    {
       var vm = this;

       vm.name = $localStorage.name;
       vm.userId = $localStorage._id;

       vm.readNotifications = function(notifId){
          $http({
               url: 'http://192.168.2.8:7200/api/readNotification',
               method: 'POST',
               data: {notificationId: notifId,  userId: vm.userId}
           }).then(function(res){
              vm.rslt = res.data.result1;
              console.log(vm.rslt);
              vm.refresh();
              $location.path('/sharedwishlistdetails');
            }, function(error){
               alert(error.data);
            })
         }
      }
})();
```

### toolbar.hrml

```
<div class="notification">
    <md-menu id="language-menu" md-offset="0 60" md-position-mode="target-right target" >
        <md-button class="md-fab md-mini " aria-label="Bell" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">
            <md-icon md-svg-src="assets/icons/fonts/bell.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>

        <md-menu-content  style="height:150px; overflow:auto; ">
            <div class="notifi" ng-repeat="notification in vm.result">
                <md-menu-item ng-hide="vm.showMessage" ng-repeat="name in notification.notificationDetails">
                    <md-button  ng-click="vm.readNotifications(notification._id); vm.findWishlist(notification._id)"> 
                        <b>{{name.userName}}</b> shared wishlist with you. 
                    </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
                <span><hr flex/></span>
            </div> 

            <md-menu-item ng-show="vm.showMessage">
                <md-button ng-click="">
                    No notifications.
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
            <a ui-sref="app.notifications" style="text-align:center; font-size:14px">See All</a>
        </md-menu-content>
    </md-menu>
    <div ng-show="vm.showBadge" class="badge bg-danger up">{{vm.CountTrue}}</div>   
</div>
```

### toolbar.module.js

```
(function ()
{
   'use strict';

    angular
       .module('app.toolbar', [])
       .config(config);
    function config($stateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider)
    {
       $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('app/toolbar');

       $stateProvider.state('app.toolbar', {
          url    : '/sharedwishlistdetails',
          views  : {
               'content@app': {
                   templateUrl: 'app/toolbar/sharedwishlistdetails.html',
                   controller : 'ToolbarController as vm'
                }
           }
       });   
    }
})();
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Angular js is used to work with single page applications.You can try to use routing in your code.

Comment: @pritishvaidya That's actually not true. AngularJS can be used in any web application. It doesn't have  to be a single page application.

Comment: One way would be to write a shared service

Comment: where  readNotifications calls from ? Show code.

Comment: @ValeryKozlov I have updated my question. In `toolbbar.html` readNotifications calls.

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct, when suppose that your code is smth like :

```
   $stateProvider.state('app.toolbar', {
      url    : '/sharedwishlistdetails',
      views  : {
           'content@app': {
               templateUrl: 'app/toolbar/toolbar.html',
               controller : 'ToolbarController as vm'
            },
            'list@app': {
                   templateUrl: 'app/toolbar/sharedwishlistdetails.html',
                   controller : 'ToolbarController as vm'
            }
       }
   });
```

If so - your template have distinct instances of controller with unrelated data, so each controller should load data independently.

If I miss with suggestion - please provide call to tada from sharedwishlistdetails.html and it's view\route.